# Randomize() in vb.net not randomizing properly

Tags: vb.net

What is wrong with this code? It is called in groups of four, and always seems to wind up with only two combinations:

```
Public Function GetRand() As String
        Randomize()
        Dim r As Integer = CInt(Rnd() * 3)
        Select Case r
            Case 0
                Return str1
            Case 1
                Return str2
            Case 2
                Return str3
            Case 3
                Return str4
            Case Else
                Return str1
        End Select
    End Function
```

It is returning random strings, but it seems to be returning them in a non-random order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definately chaeck out the Random object that @zawaideh mentions:

```
    Static R As New Random()  'Static so that it only gets initialized once'
    R.Next(0, 4)              'Returns an integer from zero up to but not including 4, so 0,1,2,3'
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem probably is the call to `Randomize()`. Take it out and it should work fine.
When calling `Randomize()`, you are setting the seed the random number generator will use. You should only call it once, otherwise you might be seeding it always with the same value.

Comment: Yup.  It uses the current clock tick to seed the randomizer.  That tick doesn't change very fast (15.625 msec).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using VB.Net you can use the .net random number generator

```
Dim random_object As New Random()
Console.WriteLine(random_object.Next().ToString())
```